# How to use Timestamp in a Map as key

Tags: java, hashmap, timestamp

I am working on a coding challenge on a banking application where I need to fetch number of transactions in last 60 seconds.
For that I am using `java.sql.Timestamp` as a key of a `map` like below:

```
Map<Timestamp, List<Transaction>> transactions1 = new HashMap<>();
```

Here value is the list of transactions done at that time.
***I can't use DB***. I know how to iterate through the map and fetch the data but for that I need to iterate the whole `map` which will be time consuming.

> 1) My question is is `Map` the right data structure for this problem?
>
> 2) If so then how can I reduce it(may be by `NavigableMap`)?

I am not asking for coding solution but the proper design/ data structure that I should use.

Comment: why don't you use epoch timestamp as key `1534698909` so that you sort map based on keys and get the values

Comment: I’d say `Timestamp` is the wrong class. One, it’s long outdated, two, it was designed for use with an SQL database. Consider `Instant` or another class from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: If all you need is the number of transactions, it suffices to store the number for each time (you don’t need the list of actual transactions). I’d consider a list of pairs of time and number, keeping the list sorted by time. Then it suffices to find the earliest count within the last minutes and adding up the numbers from that point. We don’t know enough about your requirements to tell whether this a good solution, though, which is why I voted to close your question an unclear.

Answer (score 3):

A HashMap solely considers mapping (based on hash code and equality).

This means: you have to `get()` **all** keys of your map, to ensure you correctly identify those within a certain interval. No shortcuts possible, always a full O(n) scanning of **all** keys in your map.

Thus you are correct: any efficient strategy must allow you to *search* that map (in an array/random access based approach), so maps implementing the NavigableMap, such as [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) will be a better choice. TreeMaps are also sorted, so you could implement some way of "binary search" to identify timestamps from the last n seconds. Meaning: you need O(log n) to determine the first timestamp within the interval, and then you just keep fetching the *following* keys, until you reach the upper bound of the interval.

Beyond that, it could be helpful to invest in your own implementation of some sort of *index*. Like a list that remembers the first timestamp of 1/5/n minute intervals.

Meaning: the low hanging fruit is to simply change from HashMap to TreeMap, with clever searching for interval boundaries. But for a "real world" scenario, where you might have to deal with hundreds of thousands or millions of entries, that approach is still not sufficient. Then you would have to very carefully design a solution that optimizes on your most important requirements. But that is something that only you can do.

Answer (score 1):

One way to increase performance is to dump the inner `for` loop. By adding a `List<Transaction>` in the `HashMap` you'll have to use a loop inside another loop to access the `Transaction` object.

---

Use,

```
HashMap<Long, Transaction> transactions = new HashMap<>();
```

And use Nanoseconds as the key.

```
System.nanoTime();
```

So when iterating you have the `Transaction` object right away. If you want to get the `Timestamp`,

```
new Timestamp(nanoseconds/1000000);
```

Comment: Still, this means to iterate the map in **full** length, based on a non-sorted order. Sure, your idea makes the lookup a bit faster, but it still means that you always always always have to go through **all** entries in the map. Because you have to check each and any key. This mean you have O(n). All the time. Compare that with sorting the keys, and being able to do binary search to identify the first key that needs to be considered!

Comment: But there could be scenario where there were two transactions at the same time. In that case the value will be overwritten. I know nanoseconds is less chance but quite possible right?

Comment: @J.Doe yeah, it's possible. But it's very rare like 1 million : 1.

Comment: `System.nanotime()` doesn’t give you a well-defined point in time, so you are not obtaining a valid timestamp. `Instant.now()` is an option.